# How do I get reliable scale ticks with bar plots that sum up numbers into single bars in ggplot (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, geom-bar

I have a simple ggplot bar plot which displays information about school expenses.
It retrieves it's information from a data-frame with the following columns:

- Where the purchase was made (there are two recurrent locations)
- What was the purchase amount in dollars

You can take a closer look at this data at the end of this post (csv format).

Each bar in my plot represents a different purchase location. The bars stacks multiple colours for each purchase made (proportional to its amount). Here is a look at my plot:

[image: Example plot]

As you can see, the scaling is clearly off (the 10.28 tick is about a third as high as the 215.25 tick in the y axis).

**How should I go about making the scaling accurate and what is causing this inaccurate y axis?**

Here is my raw csv file:

```
"DATE"      ;"MONTANT";"LIEU"                      ;"CAUSE"
"2020-01-25";    67.17;"Coop Cégep"                ;"Notes de cours"
"2020-02-24";     7.67;"Coop Cégep"                ;"Notes de cours"
"2020-01-30";    10.28;"Coop Cégep"                ;"Cahiers d'exercices"
"2020-03-02";   215.25;"Omnivox (Cégep Lanaudière)";"Frais de scholarité"
"2020-01-22";   114.60;"Coop Cégep"                ;"Romans, Notes de cours"
"2020-08-27";    78.33;"Coop Cégep"                ;"Romans, Notes de cours"
"<++>"      ;     <++>;"<++>"                      ;"<++>"
```

Here is the code I used to generate this image:

```
#!/bin/Rscript

# LIBRARIES ----

library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

# CSV's ----

expenses <- head(data.frame(read.csv("paiements.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")), -1)
expenses$DATE  <- as.Date(expenses$DATE)

# PLOTS ----

# Bar plot with different expenses sorted by location
expenses_df <- ggplot(expenses, aes(LIEU, MONTANT, fill=MONTANT)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    geom_jitter(width=0.1, height=0, shape=18, size=4) +
    labs(
             title="Montants de diverses dépenses scholaires",
             x="Lieu",
             y="Montant") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))

# JPEG ----

jpeg(
        file="paiements.jpg",
)

print(expenses_df)

dev.off()
```

**Data in `dput` format**

```
expenses <-
structure(list(DATE = c("2020-01-25", "2020-02-24", "2020-01-30", 
"2020-03-02", "2020-01-22", "2020-08-27"), MONTANT = c(67.17, 
7.67, 10.28, 215.25, 114.6, 78.33), LIEU = c("Coop Cégep", "Coop Cégep", 
"Coop Cégep", "Omnivox (Cégep Lanaudière)", "Coop Cégep", 
"Coop Cégep"), CAUSE = c("Notes de cours", "Notes de cours", 
"Cahiers d'exercices", "Frais de scholarité", "Romans, Notes de cours", 
"Romans, Notes de cours")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Looks like MONTANT wasn't read into R as a numerical variable. If you wish to ignore the last row of your raw data, consider specifying `nrow` in `read.csv` to only read in the first 7 rows.

Comment: Why `fill = MONTANT`? Doesn't it make a lot more sense `fill=CAUSE`? Also, package `RColorBrewer` is not used in the code example.

Comment: Whatever data you have provided the code works fine except `fill=as.factor(MONTANT)` and `fill = "MONTANT"` within `labs`. You can test the variable type using `str(expenses)`. As suggested by @Z.Lin, I am sure in your case the MONTANT is a character variable not numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the last file line. The character string `"<++>"` ending each column is messing up the numeric column `MONTANT`. Here is a way of solving it.

1. Coerce the column `MONTANT` to numeric;
2. Vector elements that cannot be numeric become `NA`, with a warning `"NAs introduced by coercion"`;
3. Remove those rows with `!is.na(.)`.

The code will be the following.

```
expenses$MONTANT <- as.numeric(expenses$MONTANT)
expenses <- expenses[!is.na(expenses$MONTANT), ]
```

Now coerce the date column to class `"Date"` and plot. I have filled the bars with `CAUSE` defining their color.

```
expenses$DATE  <- as.Date(expenses$DATE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(expenses, aes(LIEU, MONTANT, fill = CAUSE)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_jitter(width=0.1, height=0, shape=18, size=4) +
  labs(
    title="Montants de diverses dépenses scholaires",
    x="Lieu",
    y="Montant") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]